# Unable to run asp.net core docker image - framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.1.1' was not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker

I am following the tutorial found here (I'm a Docker beginner)

https://medium.com/@alcalawilfre/asp-net-core-with-docker-a-beginers-guide-4f490f644a89

I have followed all the information and have the following dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./src/AspMVC/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "AspMVC.dll"]
```

When I try to run the docker image I get the below error.

```
S C:\aspnetcore-docker> docker run -p 5000:80 myimage
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.1.1' was not found.
```

However I do have the runtime installed.

```
S C:\aspnetcore-docker> dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
```

Can anyone assist as to where I've gone wrong? I've tried installing the runtimes manually onto my machine, and targeting other images in the FROM section of the dockerfile, but this error never changes.

Comment: Docker doesn't use runtimes installed in your computer. It depends on the image. Try to specify image version like `FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:latest`

Comment: Seems that latest aspnetcore images is moved to [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core-aspnet)